# With Python xlrd can you convert a money field to text in an xlsx file?

Tags: python, excel

I am using SQL Server to bulk load some xlrd files into a SQL table, but need to convert money fields to text to remove commas before converting to CSV using Python. Can I do this with xlrd?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some logic like below:

```
    import xlrd
    import xlwt
    from xlutils.copy import copy 

    # reading
    book = xlrd.open_workbook('original.xls') # read original excel
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    col = 1  # the column where you need to change

    # writing
    wb = copy(book)  # copy
    worksheet = wb.get_sheet(0)

    for row in range(0, sheet.nrows):
        for column in range(0, sheet.ncols):
            if column == col:   # compare here
                val = sheet.cell(row, column).value # fetch value
                val_modified = str(val) # modify value
                worksheet.write(row, column, val_modified) # write to excel

    wb.save('new.xls') # save as new excel
```